# Socket.IO + Node.JS пару вопросов

Tags: node.js, socket.io

При написании простинького чата, возникли следующие вопросы:

1. Как индифицировать пользователя или проверять, что данное сообщение отправил именно этот пользователь, а не кто-то другой, чтобы избежать подмены ников? (session cookie etc?)
2. Как отправить сообщение, определённому пользователю, а не всем, кто находиться в чате?
3. Как лучше хранить активных участников форума? (массив или БД)

Помогите, кто чем может :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Когда ты создаешь новый сокет при подключении - это javascript объект, к тому-же уникальный, соответственно ничто не мешает тебе хранить информацию о пользователе (имя, ник, сколько лет, цвет ника, да что угодно собственно, главное что-бы не затирало уже существующие свойства или методы объекта).

Вообщем, по хорошему, я бы сделал как-то так

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8000);
var sockets = [];
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    sockets.push(socket);
    socket.session = {}; // здесь хранить необходимые данные 
    // например напишем реализацию инициализация ника пользователя
    // естественно ник должен быть уникальным
    // если переданный ник уже существует - отвечаем ошибкой 
    // если нет - записываем в ранее созданный объект session

    socket.on('setNickName', function(nickName) {
        function isUnique(nickName) {
            var isUnique = true;   // по умолчанию ник уникален
            // пройдемся циклом по всем сокетам
            for(var i=0, i<sockets.length; ++i) {
                // если у кого-то уже есть такой ник - значит он не уникален
                if(sockets[i].session.nickName === nickName) {
                     isUnique = false;   // ник не уникален
                     break;              // покидаем цикл
                }
            }
            return isUnique;
        }
        if(isUnique(nickName)) {
             // если ник таки уникален
             this.session.nickName = nickName; // пишем в "сессию"
             this.emit('nickNameInitialized', {error: null, nickName : nickName});
             // оповещаем клиента о том что все прошло нормально
        }
        else {
             // в противном случае оповещаем клиента об ошибке
             this.emit('nickNameInitialized', {error: "Ник занят", nickName : nickName});
        }
    })
});
```

Естественно реализацию всего остального я не затрагивал и писать подобный код "в лоб" - неправильно, но с обвертками и тому подобными вещами, думаю, вы и сами разберетесь, а если нет - онивам или не нужны или вам нужно учить матчасть.

Реализацию клиента думаю писать не надо, там должно быть все понятно и так.

Ну а дальше все стандартно, сессия уникальна, id формируеться при подключении, добавить проверку на занятость ника, возможно добавить пароль и все - profit.

Это по поводу "сессий". Еще хотел бы добавить - естественно этот подход неприменим в контексте http сервера. (думаю это и так понятно, но на всякий случай уточняю)

---

Теперь по поводу определенному пользователю:
Все довольно просто, все тот-же цикл for. Например - реализовывается функция на клиенте, вида:

```
 // socket - Объект получений после вызова io.connect
 // это я тоже на всякий случай
 function sendPrivateMessage(nickName, message) {
       socket.emit('sendPrivateMessage', {nickName : nickName, message : message});
 }
 // как этот врапер будет выполняться - это дело ваше

 //=================================================
 // ну и на сервере обработчик вида

 socket.on('sendPrivateMessage', function(params) {

     for(var i=0, i<sockets.length; ++i) {
           var tmp = sockets[i];
           var sended = false;
           if(tmp.session.nickName === params.nickName) {
                tmp.emit('privateMessage', {
                    sender : socket.session.username,
                    message : params.message
                }); // оповещаем получателя
                socket.emit('privateMessageSended',{
                    err : null,
                    nickName : params.nickName
                }); // оповещаем отправителя
                sended = true;
           }
     }

     if(!sended) { // если пользователя с таким ником не существует
          var err  = "Пользователя с ником ";
              err += params.nickName
              err += " не существует";
          socket.emit('privateMessageSended', {
               err :  err
          })
     }

 })
```

Опять таки - быстро и грязно, но суть, надеюсь, ясна.

---

Ну и по поводу БД - все зависит от того собираетесь ли вы хранить историю чата (старые сообщения), ну, или, например - считать количество сообщений того или иного пользователя.
Тогда, естественно, бд необходима.

В любом случае - если в планах реализация авторизации вида ник, пароль. Эти данные тоже нужно где-то хранить. Правда исключительно для этих целей работать с БД нет смысла, достаточно хранить данные в текстовом файл в формате .json и, при старте сервера, собирать их в массив( т.е. в оперативную память ).

Вообщем - если чат простой БД не нужна, если же в планах всякого рода плюшки и т.д. - скорее всего, нужна.

PS: удачи в реализации

Comment: Забыл добавить - если чат highload, не забываем юзать `process.nextTick` и вместо синхронных циклов - пишим асинхронные.

Comment: Еще для облегчения работы с сессиями можно воспользоваться оберткой [Socket.IO-sessions](https://github.com/aviddiviner/Socket.IO-sessions). Тогда сессия будет передаваться вам непосредственно в обработчик `socket.on('sendPrivateMessage', function(params, session) { ... });`