# Node.js, socket.io: Как настроить tickrate, частоту обращения клиента к серверу

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Здравствуйте. Делаю чат на node.js + socket.io. Возникла проблема. На достаточно мощном сервере "всего" при 1000 чел онлайн загрузка достигает 100%. Я новичок в использовании нода. Начал выяснять в чем причина, на этом же сайте умный человек говорил о тикрейте, то есть о возможности настроить частоту обращения клиента к серверу и обратно. В манах примеров нет.

Не могли бы вы привести кусок кода, будет здорово если с развернутыми комментариями, где используется tickrate, например, клиент обращается к серверу каждые 3 секунды.

Спасибо.

Дополню. Вот вопрос с ответом: 
[Socket.IO + Node.JS пару вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/79766/socket-io-node-js-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Там в самом конце, уже в комментах к последнему ответу, чел пишет: "Забыл добавить - если чат highload, не забываем юзать process.nextTick ". Как им пользоваться? Как ни странно, примеров не нашел, хотя искал прилично. Может не фартануло (

Comment: а зачем у вас при socket.io вообще частые обращения ? вы установите соединение и по нему гоняйте данные  - установка соединения весьма тяжелая операция.

Comment: так мне и не нужны частые обращения, я как раз хочу от них избавиться. соединение сохраняется, но обмен данными не чаще чем определенная величина

Comment: чет крутовато для 1000 человек чтобы проц так нагружался, может у вас данные такие или обработчики тяжелые ?

Comment: там говорили про nextTick, это такой способ типа setTimeout(funct,0);

http://howtonode.org/understanding-process-next-tick