# Чат node.js + socket.io

Tags: socket.io

В общем недавно набрел вот на такую [статью](http://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/51453/) , про то как организовать личные сообщения на Socket.io + MySQL. Меня очень заинтересовала эта идея, решил попробовать сделать что-нибудь. Установил node.js, необходимые модули, запустил сервер, создал таблицу сообщений и пользователей. Но я абсолютно не понимаю как организовать messages.php, чтобы например получать id пользователя к примеру при нажатии на его имя на странице.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Там можно без php вообще обойтись, все обрабатывать на стороне нода.

Помотри код:
https://github.com/vanbosse/websockets-demo

А потом прочти:
[Socket.IO + Node.JS пару вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/79766/socket-io-node-js-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Тебе нужно создать асинхронный запрос к ноду. Нод проверит ID и даст ответ. Если я правильно понял, что нужно.